# yajra/laravel-datatables filterColumn doesnt work

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Page loading correctly and every things work fine while bringing datas. Now I want to filter them but FilterColumn() method doesnt even work. When I tried filter() method it's working but then I won't get $keywords variable. I am missing something while querying leads ?

```
if (request()->ajax()) {
        $leads = Lead::with('country','agent','detail')->orderBy('id','DESC');

        $leads->where(function($q) use ($user){
            if ($user->hasRole('agent')  && !$user->hasRole('admin') && !$user->hasRole('lead')){  //agent isem
                $q->where('agent_id',$user->id)
                ->orWhere('agent_id',null);
            }
        });

        return DataTables::of($leads)->
        addColumn('edit_button', function ($lead) {
            $link  = route('leads.edit',$lead->id);
            return '<a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm ad-click-event"> Edit </a>';
        })->
        filterColumn('edit_button', function ($query, $keyword) {
            dd($keyword);
            return $query->whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
                $query->whereRaw("CONCAT( name,  ' ', surname ) like ?", ["%$keyword%"]);
            });
        })->rawColumns(['edit_button','phone','detail.conversion_notes'])->

        toJson();
}
 $tableColumn = [
        ['data' => 'edit_button', 'name' => 'edit_button', 'title' => 'Edit', 'searchable' => false],
        ['data' => 'full_name', 'name' => 'full_name', 'title' => 'Full Name'],
        ['data' => 'phone', 'name' => 'phone', 'title' => 'Phone'],
        ['data' => 'email', 'name' => 'email', 'title' => 'Email'],
        ['data' => 'country.name', 'name' => 'country.name', 'title' => 'Country'],

        ['data' => 'agent.name', 'name' => 'agent.name', 'title' => 'Agent'],
        ['data' => 'treatment', 'name' => 'treatment', 'title' => 'Treatment'],
        ['data' => 'find_us', 'name' => 'find_us', 'title' => 'Find Us'],
        ['data' => 'form_type', 'name' => 'form_type', 'title' => 'Form','visible' => false],
        ['data' => 'social_account', 'name' => 'social_account', 'title' => 'Sosyal Medya'],
        ['data' => 'created_at', 'name' => 'created_at', 'title' => 'Created At'],
        ['data' => 'detail.conversion_notes', 'name' => 'detail.conversion_notes', 'title' => 'Primary Notes'],
    ];


    $html = $builder->columns($tableColumn)->parameters([
        "pageLength" => 25,
        "lengthMenu" => [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
        'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
        'columnDefs' => [
            ['width' => '2%', 'targets' => 0],
            ['width' => '7%', 'targets' => 1],
        'buttons' => [
            'pageLength',
            [
                'extend' => 'colvis',
                'collectionLayout' => 'fixed two-column',
                'columns' => ':not(.noVis)'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: You could remove the "dd()" which may cause Bad ajax content returned to datatable JS. (maybe is not the problem ?

Comment: @FrédéricKlee no that is for testing. The main problem is, even dd() doesnt work. It just skiping filterColumn method

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I believe that filterColumn only works on columns which exist in a DB table. Is there a edit_button column in you table?